# Number does not increment when using ActiveX Command button placed in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

This project has a `UserForm` that fills in data into a table. For new data, it will add a new row and give an index number in increments of 1.

When I press run on `VBA`, the project works as it should.

But when I placed a Command Button in the Excel, to open the `UserForm`, and then add new data, a new row is created but the number starts from 1 and subsequent too.

Code for Command Button in the Excel to open the `UserForm` (`DataEntry` is the UserForm):

```vb
Private Sub ackCommandButton_Click()

    Load DataEntry: DataEntry.dataentryMP.Value = 0: DataEntry.Show
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to restart your index with `DataEntry.dataentryMP.Value = 0`. Try removing it.